# The following vectors are linearly independent if and only if k≠

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Does anybody know how to solve this Question ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdRck.jpg

I managed to get K= to a number so that there is a solution, but apparently it is wrong and I have to find that k!= something..

Comment: can you include your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Find what linear combination $(3,-9)$ is of $(-4,7)$ and $(2,-4)$.  You'll get $(3,-9)=a(-4,7)+b(2,-4)$ for certain $a,b$.  Then we get that $11a+6b+kb=-12$.  Solve for $k$.

Comment: Thank you sirrr